# Can you identify this Multi-Select dropdown with checkboxes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'm looking for this control, which is definitely not stock.  It's on a website that I won't link so people don't think I'm spamming.  In its native state, it looks like this:
[image]

and when selected, it drops down like this:
[image]

I don't know if the language used is C# or VB, but I know the page has an ASPX extension.

If you can't identify the exact control, can you suggest a way to do something similar in a C#/ASP.Net environment?

Comment: http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/

Comment: @adt - If you make this an answer, I can give you points.  After I looked at this (and the corresponding github page) and then picked apart the source page I found it on, the names all match.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it both with Javascript/Jquery and server side.

The control you're after called  [CheckBoxList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

it looks like :

[image]

if it is hosted within a `DIV` you can get the scroller thingy.

Regarding  :

[image]

it is a `DIV` which  , when clicked , shows the `div` i've talked about.

Example [here](http://jsbin.com/yezuto/2/edit) :

[image]