# jquery trouble - Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've seen a couple questions on this but my issue doesn't seem to be related.

I have this at the top of an ASPX page:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="HeaderContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Styles/jquery.multiselect.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.multiselect.min.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#test-1").multiselect({
                header: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

My scripts are definitely in the Scripts folder (case sensitive).  Still, when I run the code, I get the "'$' is undefined" error.  When I break the code, the last 2 lines are underlined in red, and when I hover over them it indicates an "Expected /" error.

I've tried it without the "~" in the path and using 2 dots in the path as well, with the same results.

The page will load, but the multi-select dropdown I'm trying to use doesn't look the way it should.

**EDIT:**
After I've run the code, the page source looks like this:

```
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /><title>
    Register - My ASP.NET Application
</title><script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>

 <!-- <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  -->
    <link href="../favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" /><link href="../Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Styles/jquery.multiselect.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.multiselect.min.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#test-1").multiselect({
                header: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Would you mind to clarify what problem you have? (404 on script files, script errors even if JQuery loaded, something else)?

Comment: Can you check to see if there are any other JavaScript errors on the console in your browser? Maybe the scripts aren't loading, or something else is breaking first.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - The code runs in VS2012, but it breaks at the "$(function() {" line with the above error.  Then it appears to continue running, but my dropdown isn't behaving the way it should.  This is entirely running on localhost at the moment, I don't publish until it runs properly.

Comment: can you create jsfidder for the issue , it seems there is issue with plugin .

Comment: In MVC4 projects I had a similar issue. I call `$.noConflict();` and from there on I use `jQuery(...)` instead of `$(...)`.

Comment: move the JavaScript to the bottom of the page, just above footer and see.

Comment: @Rex - Now it's changed to - "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'multiselect'"

Comment: In the rendered output, the path to modernizr uses a different relative path form. The "Object doesn't support property or method 'multiselect" means that indicates that jQuery is loading but your the plugin is not loading.

Comment: Anyway, set a breakpoint at the at the top of the inline script and evaluate $, $('#test-1'), and $('#test-1') in the console.

Comment: @JohnnyBones move references to the library to the page end too and try.

Comment: @Rex - Welp, it's not giving me any more errors, but it's still not working the way it should.  The dropdown is still not looking the way it should.  See [this question I posted yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558060/can-you-identify-this-multi-select-dropdown-with-checkboxes) for what it's supposed to look like.  Instead, it looks like a listbox with a scroll bar.

Comment: OK, 95% there.  Had to change the dollar sign to "jQuery".  Now it works, minus a little CSS which I'll clean up.